# How to Create and Get Preference Values in Android

Tags: android

Code: https://github.com/DanSolomon/CMSC434-Clock

There's a single preference (in xml / pref_general.xml) in a separate settings activity. I need to be able to store the current value of the preference and get the value in the main activity.

I can't figure out if it's storing the value correctly and if it is, how to get the value from storage.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Try to give a small working example of code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the SettingsActivity:

`PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));`

while the preference.getKey() is the key in your xml-definition.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. How would I get the value in the Main Activity?

Comment: exactly the same way. String value = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()) .getString("theKey", ""));

Comment: In the Main Activity then, what would be preference? It's part of the function in the Settings Activity.

Comment: sorry, it is the context, so you can use `String value = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("example_list2", "");`

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very confusing to me and you've clarified it very well. It's appreciated.